# How to pass object to partial using controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've been trying to pass my Product object to my rendered partial but no matter what I try it doesn't work. The home page has a quick view button that pops a modal (the partial) and I want to pass the correct product to it.

Route

```
get 'shop-product-ajax-page', to: "pages#shop_product_ajax_page"
```

Home Page (shortened to only the link for brevity)

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= link_to "Quick View", shop_product_ajax_page_path, :data => {:lightbox => 'ajax'} %>
<% end %>
```

Controller Action

```
def shop_product_ajax_page
  render :partial => 'pages/shop_product_ajax_page', :layout => false
end
```

Right now, the button works and displays the HTML in the modal. I want to be able to populate the correct product information for whatever Quick View product is selected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the link is making a completely separate AJAX request, it's hitting the server separately, so the Ruby context you expect (variables etc) isn't available in that new request.

Two choices:

- Don't make an AJAX request but render the lightbox as part of the page. You could hide it using `display: none` or similar, then use Javascript to display it when the link is clicked.
- Make the request the way you currently are, but pass in the same parameters that your current controller action is using to get `@products` and in `shop_product_ajax_page` do the same thing to hit the database and get the products.

The second choice might be easier without messing with JS. It would be something like:

```
def shop_product_ajax_page
  @products = get_products_from_params(params)
  render :partial => 'pages/shop_product_ajax_page', :layout => false
end

private

  def get_products_from_params(params)
    Product.find(params["product_ids"]) # or whatever you're currently doing
  end
```

Comment: But is there a way to pass the product through the link itself? Like `shop_product_ajax_page_path(product)`?

Comment: @TonyS. usually it would be something like `shop_product_ajax_page_path(id: product.id)`, which would add the ID as a parameter to the request, so the URL would look something like `https://yourdomain.com/shop/product/ajax?id=<product.id>`.